# Criar DropDownList com ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

> InvalidOperationException: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'Office'.

Aqui busco do banco de dados:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetAllOfficeAsync(Guid user)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<SelectListItem> result =  _context.FuncionariosCargo.Where(x => x.UsuarioId == user)
                                                      .OrderBy(x => x.Cargo)
                                                      .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                                      {
                                                          Value = c.Id.ToString(),
                                                          Text = c.Cargo
                                                       });


         return result;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Aqui crio a ViewBag:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

    if (user == null)
    {
        throw new ApplicationException($"Não é possível carregar o usuário com o ID '{_userManager.GetUserId(User)}'.");
    }

    var model = await _employeeManager.SearchEmployee(search.ToString(), page, user.Id);

    ViewBag.Office = _employeeManager.GetAllOfficeAsync(user.Id);

    return View(model);
}
```

E por ultimo a View, aonde tento criar o campo:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Office", ViewBag.Office as SelectList, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Esse erro costuma ocorrer quando a lista é vazia (null). Se você debuggar sua view a ViewBag.Office tem informações?

Comment: ah entendi, e caso eu não tenha nenhum valor na ViewBag, teria como retornar o valor em branco ou apenas "Seleciona sua opção", algo desse genero ?

Comment: Você pode tratar de algumas maneiras, vou montar uma resposta pra você já incluindo o problema da lista ser vazia.

Comment: Beleza, aguardo sua resposta então @GeorgeWurthmann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro pode estar ocorrendo por que sua `ViewBag.Office` está vázia (null).

Para evitar o problema você pode tratar o campo de algumas formas.

1- Exemplo para por um valor genérico na lista na controller:

```
if(((SelectList)ViewBag.Office) == null)
{
    ViewBag.Office = new SelectList(new[] {
         new SelectListItem  { Value="0", Text="Valores não encontrados" }
    }, "Value", "Text");
}
```

2- Exemplo para só mostrar o campo se o mesmo não for nulo na View:

```
@if (ViewBag.Office != null)
{
    @Html.DropDownList("Office", ViewBag.Office as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
}
```